# Passing parameter value to Stored Procedure used in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, mysql, crystal-reports

I am using VS 2012 with Crystal Reports.
I have written a stored Procedure in MySQL with one parameter , i am using this stored procedure in my Crystal report, everything works fine but when i use export option of crystal report and i export the report to PDFs format, it contains empty report as i have set Parameter value to null in Design Time of crystal report. My code s given below.

```
protected void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string qry = "Call SP_GeneralReport ('" + tbx_ddoCode.Text.ToUpper() + "')";
        DataSet ds = Q.sendQueryToReport(qry);
        ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
        crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("GeneralEmpReport.rpt"));
        crystalReport.SetDatabaseLogon("root", "", "localhost", "hr");
        crystalReport.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReport;
    }
public DataSet sendQueryToReport(string qry)
    {
        //- if connection is closed then open the connection
        if (myConn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            myConn.Open();

        //- Create command and then assign Query
        myComm = new MySqlCommand(qry, myConn);


        myAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(myComm);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        myAdapter.Fill(ds);
        // finally close the connection
        myConn.Close();
        return ds;  
    }
```

In browser i pass parameter value to stored procedure using textbook, it show the accurate result in browser , but the problem comes when i export my report then it show me empty report. As to mention here in Design of Crystal report i set default value of storedprocedure to null.

Answer (score 0):

First set EnableParmeterPrompt property of CrystalReportviewer to true and  then pass the parameter to the stored procedure object through Crystalreport object as given below -

`crystalReport.SetParameterValue(0, "parameterValue");`